# With filePond how do I get custom data i.e. galleryId (custom) back to client when file(s) uploaded?

Tags: filepond

Using filePond to upload image(s), how can I decorate the request with data such as for example galleryId, and respond with decorated data? Or is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `ondata` property:

```
pond.setOptions({
    server: {
        process: {
            url: './',
            ondata: (formData) => {
                formData.append('galleryId', 'galleryId');
                return formData;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See the Docs: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#configuration